# How I can test form_valid method from CreateView class

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-tests

I have a Class view that inherits of CreateView

```
class CreateErrandView(ErrandFormMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ErrandForm

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("passes through here")
        return super(CreateErrandView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form, formset):
        print("create some transactions")
        print("not pass through here")
        return super(CreateErrandView, self).form_valid(form, formset)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("passes through here")
        return super(CreateErrandView, self).post(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I need write a test that make a post and execute form_valid method

I wrote

```
class ErrandTransactionsTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()

    def test__test_valid_form(self):
        # Arrange
        form_data = {
            u'type': 'taxi'
        }  

        form = ErrandForm(data=form_data)

        # Act
        self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(), True)
        response = self.c.post(reverse('errands_create'), form_data)

        # Assert
        self.assertEqual(len(Transactions.objects.all()), 5)
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What is in `ErrandFormMixin`?

Comment: Another Class that not implemented form_valid

Comment: As I remember, `CreateView` has no `formset` parameter in `form_valid`. Did you check what in `response`?

Comment: Then you'll need to overwrite `post` to call it correctly. Look at [ProcessFormView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L163)

Comment: Thanks sneawo you are right, the problem was in the post defined in ErrandFormMixin.. has the following code: if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid(): return self.form_valid(form, formset) and the formset.is_valid() are false